# domXpath get ancestor node

Tags: php, domxpath

I have the following html structure :

```
<a class="class1" href="link">
   <div class="class2" id="result_0">
      <img imgstuffhere />      
         <div class="class3">
           <span>text</span>
        </div>
   </div>
</a>
<a class="class1" href="link">
   <div class="class2" id="result_0">
      <img imgstuffhere />      
         <div class="class3">
           <span>text</span>
        </div>
   </div>
</a>
etc....
```

I'm parsing the page using domXPath. I'm able to get each block by doing

```
$items = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' class1 ')]");
```

then i loop on items set of results :

```
foreach($items as $item){
    $name = $xpath->query("descendant::*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' class3 ')]", $item)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    etc...
}
```

My problem is, in the loop, i need to get the href link located in the class1  node.

I tried to play around with ancestor stuff, but impossible to make it works.

**ANSWER**

```
$link = $item->getAttribute('href');
```

Simply did the trick.

Comment: Isn't $item the `<a class="class1" href="link">` element? You already have it.

Comment: `contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' class1 ')` can be made far more efficient by just writing `contains(@class, 'class1')`

Comment: @Jessica Yes, but how can i get the link ?

Answer (score 1):

`$item` is a [DomNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) representing the `a` element you selected.

It has an attributes property which is a [DOMNamedNodeMap](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnamednodemap.getnameditem.php) you should be able to access. If the property you want is href:

```
$link = $item->attributes->getNamedItem("href")->nodeValue;
```